# KeyError: 'TABLENAME' in mySQL database while using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm fairly new to the SQLAlchemy ORM. Im using a mySQL database whose schema I imported in a .sql file. I created the engine, connected to the database. I bound both the MetaData and the Session objects to the engine. But when I ran:

```
for t in metadata.tables:
    print(t.name)
```

I got the following error:

```
fkey["referred_table"] = rec["TABLENAME"]
KeyError: 'TABLENAME'
```

So what am I doing wrong here? It is something elementary?
Below is the full code:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import *

engine = create_engine('mysql://sunnyahlawat:miq182@localhost/sqsunny')
engine.connect()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

metadata = MetaData(bind = engine, reflect = True)
#metadata.reflect(bind = engine)

for t in metadata.tables:
    print(t.name)

#print(engine.table_names())
```

Comment: [You double-posted.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65231168/keyerror-tablename-in-mysql-database-while-using-sqlalchemy) (I'm surprised the rate limits didn't stop that.)

Comment: Maybe you simply forget to replace `TABLENAME` placeholder with actual table name?

Comment: When I try to run your code the `print(t.name)` statement throws "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'"

Comment: Its solved now. The database I had was a subset of a bigger database. But the schema had keys relating to other fields not present in the schema. Removing those keys removed this error and switching tables to sorted_tables helped remove the Attribute error

Comment: Same issue! Do you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

If the database being referred is a data dump and the table in question has foreign keys linked to an external database which has not been exported and is not on the same server, this error can come up.
The foreign key constraint fails in such a case.
A possible solution is to drop the constraint - if this is being tried out just in a test environment.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLAlchemy, at least one column (key) must be a primary key. If no column is made the primary key, then SQLAlchemy will raise an ArgumentError or KeyError.